# PHP url params and return to calling page

Tags: php

My php script is supposed to download a .zip file, and increment a counter.
In the code below, the parameters passed in on the URL are not being recognized, so the  line to download a file doesn't do anything, and if the file download doesn't work, the count loops endlessly, incrementing the count. My provider is using PHP V5.2.

I'd like for the passed parms to work, but I can live with hardcoding "myapp.zip" in the  tag.

I need to return to the page that called count.php after it's work is done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
//$Down=$_GET['Down'];
$Down=$_Post['Down'];
echo "File:" . $Down;?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <!--meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $Down;?>"/-->
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=MyApp.zip"/>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
   $filePath = 'count.txt';
   // If file exists, read current count from it, otherwise, initialize it to 0
   $count = file_exists($filePath) ? file_get_contents($filePath) : 0;
   // Increment the count and overwrite the file, writing the new value<br />
   file_put_contents($filePath, ++$count);
   // Display current download count
   //echo "Downloads:" . $count;
   //header("Location: $r.htm");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It's called from r.htm like this:

```
<form method="post" action="count.php?Down=myapp.zip" style="text-align: center">
<input type="submit" value="Download MyApp">
</form>
```

Comment: You cant do it with php only. Client made request to HTTP-server and server responce that content-type is ZIP, after downloading that cant send new header with redirect

Comment: your question is not clear, do you want to write count + 1 to 'count.txt' then redirect to the previous url?

Comment: @barif - I was afraid of that. I suppose I'll have to put a button on it. I really wanted it to be  transparent.

Comment: @razzak - Download the file, increment the counter, return to r.htm.

Comment: does it have to be in php only? you can use ajax to increment the counter without having to redirect the user!

Comment: You should really be using a database to increment the count. Additionally, you should probably have some validation of the content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (tested)

**Count.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['down'])){
$down = 'myapp.zip';
}

echo "File: <a href='$down'>$down</a>";

if(!isset($_POST['down'])){
die('NO ACCESS');

// or give them a link to go to the form and click on the button
//die('<a href="formdown.htm">Use the form to download</a>');
}

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <!--meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $Down;?>"/-->

</head>
<body>
  <?php
   $filePath = 'count.txt';
   // If file exists, read current count from it, otherwise, initialize it to 0
   $count = file_exists($filePath) ? file_get_contents($filePath) : 0;
   // Increment the count and overwrite the file, writing the new value<br />
   file_put_contents($filePath, ++$count);
   // Display current download count
   //echo "Downloads:" . $count;
   //header("Location: $r.htm");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="count.php" style="text-align: center">
<input type="hidden" name="down" value="$file" />
<input type="submit" value="Download MyApp" />
</form>
```

Comment: Mike, this could also be modified so that if someone tries to view the source to download it directly, `value="myapp.zip"` could be changed to `value="$file";` in `count.php` with code as `$file= "(path_to)myapp.zip";` (also tested).

Comment: _ Thanks, but it's just not seeing the parms on the URL. r.htm blinks, the counter is incremented, and r.htm is still in the browser.

Comment: @Mike I didn't add the redirection to `r.htm`. I figured you could modify the script to redirect to your preferred URL. Just comment out the `//header("Location: $r.htm");` - However `$r.htm` and `r.htm` are two different things.

Comment: `value="$file" ` ? you can't use php variables in html code unless you wrap it with `<?php ?>` and in this case it is undefined even if you wrap it!

Comment: @razzak It worked for me, I tested it. Copy the source files and upload one called `myapp.zip`. ;-)

Comment: you might wanna test it again without using `$file="myapp.zip"` in count.php and check what `echo $_POST['down']` output would be!

Comment: @razzak Yes I thought of that before your question, thanks. See my `edited` code. I added a `die` function with an error message. Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: @Fred Good eye on the $r.htm error. I don't understand how to use "$file='my app.zip'". I'm not totally against hardcoding the file name, but how to make that into a download? Redirection: Earlier when I was using the <meta> tag for the dl, I couldn't send another header.

Comment: @Mike See my updated source, I modified a few things. I didn't do anything for the redirection. The redirection is going to be a bit trickier.

Comment: @Mike The way that this one works, is that they click on the button from the form, it logs it as counted, then the next page gives them a link to download the file from `count.php`. If someone tries to access `count.php` directly, the counter will not increment and the user will not see the link to download the file, unless they go through the form.

Comment: @Fred Got it working. As it stands it's a hit counter rather than a download counter, right? The counter runs when the page loads, irregardless of whether the download link is clicked or not? I put a 'Back to' button on it.

Comment: @Mike It's actually a `download` counter alright. It will log/count only if someone actually `clicks` on the button from the form but will not count/log if someone accesses the count.php directly. Instead it will let them know otherwise. See the comments in the code. You can switch between them.

Comment: @Mike I came up with another version for you that will initiate the download when the user clicks on the button (will prompt the user to save the file), and it will also log/count at the same time. I can update my answer or post a new answer. Let me know what you'd like me to do. Cheers

Comment: @Fred User clicks button on htm page, goes to php page. Counter increments whether he clicks the download link on the php page or not.  Correct? I'm a tad confused. Updating the answer is fine.

Comment: @Mike Exactly. It only increments if the user clicks the download button. The other version I made will increase the counter when the user clicks the download button which will immediately prompt the user to save the file.

Comment: @Mike Why did you accept the other person's answer, confused.

Comment: @Fred OK, think I've got it now. The original(non-working) edition updated the counter when the actual download was done, not when the page loaded. Fat fingered it, it was sleepy in here.

Comment: @Mike So what did you end up doing?

Comment: @Fred I used your first cut. I have saved the second one and will try it in a couple of days.

Comment: @Mike Hey Mike how you doing? How did you make out, all good?

Comment: @Fred I left it as a hit counter, not a download counter. Got 5 hits, so it's not worth pursuing, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This version Mike, increments the counter if the user clicks the download button, which will immediately prompt the user to save the file (somewhere on their computer).

**count.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['down'])){

$filePath = 'count.txt';
   $count = file_exists($filePath) ? file_get_contents($filePath) : 0;
   // Increment the count and overwrite the file, writing the new value<br />
   file_put_contents($filePath, ++$count);

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myapp.zip");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile("myapp.zip");
}

if(!isset($_POST['down'])){
//die('NO ACCESS');

die('<a href="form.htm">Use the form to download</a>');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**The form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="count.php" style="text-align: center">
<input type="hidden" name="down" value="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Download MyApp" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```